# GHDL and VHDL - input for executable

Tags: vhdl, executable, ghdl

In windows I know that no executable is created by the command "ghdl -e something"; in linux it is created. I have to give an input file to my executable. If I was at linux I can do that by ./something < input.inp however how can I do it in windows? cause no executable is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add, because I lost time with this:
(in Windows)

```
ghdl -a "c:\superabsolutepath\test.vhdl" worked
ghdl -r my_test  resulted in: cannot load entity my_test
```

however, ghdl -d  displayed everthing correctly (the vhdl file with an absolute path)

-->use no absolute paths, by default the user folder is used "C:\Users\Lode" , when I placed my vhdl file in that folder(and start with the command

```
ghdl -a test.vhdl
ghdl -r my_test
```

, everything works, fjoeew

Answer (score 2):

On windows, no executable is generated - you should use

```
ghdl -r work.foo
```

as described [in the fine manual](http://ghdl.free.fr/ghdl/Run-command.html)